# Cant create user when user federation is enable in keycloak

Tags: keycloak

On keycloak, I want to add some users from external storage but not some.
For those who will use an external database, spi works fine, but when I want to add users who do not know about the external database directly to the local database of keyclok, I get stuck on spi and get an error.

It succeeds to add user from other use to **disable spi**. But i need more efective solution.

Can you help, please?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Keycloak you can have users both using the user spi(external data-source) and also the users directly managed by keycloak in parallel.
You don't have to disable User SPI to add keycloak managed users.
Of-course this depends on how you have implemented your SPI, but it's possible and I have tried it.
If you share more details on your user SPI implementation and error logs, it would help in suggesting a solution.

Comment: Thank you for answer. It's possible, as you said. To create a user in Keycloak, it first looks at the user cache, then its own database and then the external database. If it doesn't exist, it creates it. This is how I got it to work by changing my implementation.

Comment: @beyzanur You could help by accepting this as answer if you felt like this positively contributed to your question.